# getting a field value in html form without submitting the form

Tags: php, html

i would like to ask if it is possible to get a value from a html form without submitting the form? i cant get this to work in html or php, or maybe i'm missing something. please help. see my working code below:

```
<FORM  name="myForm" action="confirmsold.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateFormLay()">
    <table border=0 width="550" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 bgcolor="#353535" align="center">
<tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Price Basis:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ilovegym") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

        mysqli_select_db($connect, "laborsa") or die(mysqli_error());

        $sql = "SELECT Cash_Price,3months,6months,12months,18months FROM itemmaster where Item_Number='".$_SESSION['ITEM#']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

        echo "<select name='basis'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['Cash_Price'] ."'>" . $row['Cash_Price'] ." - ".CashPrice."</option><option value='" . $row['3months'] ."'>" . $row['3months'] ." - ".ThreeMonths."</option><option value='" . $row['6months'] ."'>" . $row['6months'] ." - ".SixMonths."</option><option value='" . $row['12months'] ."'>" . $row['12months'] ." - ".TwelveMonths."</option><option value='" . $row['18months'] ."'>" . $row['18months'] ." - ".EighteenMonths."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>  
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Downpayment:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><INPUT type="TEXT" name="downpayment" size="12" maxlength="11" onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"></INPUT></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Balance:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><INPUT type="TEXT" name="laybalance" size="12" maxlength="11" onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"></INPUT></td>
    </tr>
```

as you can see, i need to choose from the drowdown a payment basis, then ill input a downpayment. how can i make the balance field show the balance automatically? i only need to subtract the basis-downpayment, difference will be put in the balance field.

Please help anyone.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Client-Side vs Server-Side

PHP works purely on the server side - you can't get the value of a input element without submitting the form using PHP alone. *However*, you can do this using Javascript - this runs on the client side, rather than the server side - it is executed on the user's computer, rather than the server. This means it can run while they are on the page. Javascript can get the value of a form element for you.

### Javascript Code

Like PHP needs the `name` attribute to figure out which input field contains what information, Javascript needs the `id` attribute to get the value of an input field. First, here's the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="myAwesomeIdName">
```

Now, you need to "get" the element - this returns the HTML element as an object that Javascript can work with. This can be done using the function `document.getElementById(id)`, where `id` is the id of the HTML element. Example:

```
document.getElementById("myAwesomeIdName")
```

All that we need to do now is get the `value` attribute of the input - this is done like so:

```
document.getElementById("myAwesomeIdName").value;
```

And that returns the value of the input box.

### Putting it together

Here's some code which pops up an alert displaying the contents of an input box:

```html
<input type="text" id="myAwesomeIdName"><br><button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('myAwesomeIdName').value)">Show Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript for this. Give the three elements (`<select>`, `<input>` 1 and `<input>`2 ) also an `id="yourid"`, is somewhat more comfortable writing your javascript code.

Make your second `<input>` field `read-only` as the value is a result of a calculation and not a user input.

Write your function in javascript, and let the function be executed when the downpayment is entered, something like `oninput=mycode()`.
But let the function be executed also when the user changes the `<select>`, something like `onchange=mycode()`.

The javascript function does this (sorry, no code but procedure..)

- get the value of the `<select>` event the user has chosen
- get the value of the first `<input>` field
- subtract those values and write the result in the second read-only `<input>` field

Some considerations:

- better let the first `<option> </option>` show 'Select your method' or something like that, with a zero value attached to it. Then you can be sure the function will be triggered by the user.
- your use of the `<input>` element is incorrect. It should not have a closing tag. `</input>` is incorrect html as far as I know.
- somewhat beside the question, but `<td bgcolor="#fff">` better can be `<td style="background:#fff">`

When the values are OK the user can submit the form.